# Firebase Google Auth not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, firebase, safari, firebase-authentication

I have a function:

```
function loginWithGoogle () {
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}


firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
      if (result.credential) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      }          
      var user = result.user; // The signed-in user info.
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      var email = error.email; // The email of the user's account used.          
      var credential = error.credential; // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  });
```

Which is run when a user clicks a login button. However, this does not seem to work on Safari (using a mobile emulator and on my desktop). The code runs properly on Chrome. Is there something else I need to add to make sure Safari is supported? Thanks!

Comment: Is the login popup opening? If so, is it getting into catch{} block?  Also, please share if you notice any console errors.  In general it should work as expected, but also make sure it is not blocking popups.

Comment: @VeereshDevireddy Ah I overlooked adding an auth sign in for my x.com website (only added www.x.com). Thank you